# PostgresSQL Installation fails: "database cluster initialisation failed" MAC os

Tags: postgresql, macos

I am installing PostgreSQL (V 9.6.16) on macOS Catalina 10.15.1. Before it finishes installing I am getting the following error:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly The database cluster initialisation failed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Uninstall PostgresSQL and then clean /Library/PostgreSQL/  Directory.
2. Open teminal and run :

   sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres UserShell /bin/sh

   sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres NFSHomeDirectory /Library/PostgreSQL
3. Install PostgresSQL

Comment: I tried this solution many times but the error still occurs. I restarted the computer after complete uninstallation using the uninstaller and the command lines to delete every file and run the above commands from the root directory and then install but none of this seem to work.

Comment: This doesnt work. How can I undo the command?

Comment: This is only to transform an existing user account, so it doesn't appear as an account you can login with. A postgres user account needs to be created before you follow these steps.

Comment: @jaucourt how? What type of account? (re "A postgres user account needs to be created before you follow these steps.")

Comment: @Barry-Jon On macOS Big Sur, go into System Preferences. Choose Users and Groups. Add a new user, named 'postgres'. I created them as an admin, it might work as a normal user, not sure. Once you've done that, run the PostgreSQL installation (presuming you've not installed before, or run the uninstall). Then you can follow step 2, which keeps the postgres user account, but removes it as a login option.

Comment: This worked.  It modified an existing user from a past macports install.  Using this tool (dscl) one might be able to delete the preexisting user data, and thus have the install work from scratch.  Too lazy to try it myself.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the solutions above didn't work for me either.

I originally installed postgres via http://postgresapp.com/, however the way it works didn't fit what I needed, I followed the documentation from them to uninstall, and tried to go through https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads to install for Mac, and I kept getting:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
> correctly  The database cluster initialisation failed.

Tried a variety of things, including deleting the postgres user that's lurking in my system and reinstalling, and that didn't work either. Having said that, I think it might be helpful to remove the postgres users anyway, use:

```
dscl . list /Users
```

to see if you have postgres or _postgres users, if you do remove them with:

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete /Users/_postgres
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete /Users/postgres
```

After that, I installed via brew and created users via the commandline, I followed this:

https://www.sqlshack.com/setting-up-a-postgresql-database-on-mac/

Not gonna lie the UI and documentation around how to setup and use PGAdmin is also not great, what you'll want to do after you get through the master password dialog (just reset it worst case):

- right click on the server, and then "Register > Server"
- you'll have a modal opened to the "General" tab, name the DB as whatever you want
- and then the info listed in the tutorial for "host, user, password" etc you'll want to enter into the "Connection" tab

after that it all worked out for me.

Best of luck to anyone else that ends up running into this problem.

Comment: I think this is the answer - There is probably a profile that the installer treats as "User create, done" instead of deleting and starting from scratch.  2.5 years removed from the answer from Mirzohid, and this problem hasn't been checked and fixed.

Comment: Agree that this is the right answer and the above explanation, in my point of view, is the most appropriate reason for this

Comment: Thank you! In my case deleting postgres user after uninstalling postgres solved the issue. For others who encounter same issue make sure to uninstall postgres properly. I did it as in this site: https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-postgressql-mac

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue on MAC M1. After tried so many times I finally fixed it. Here is my solution:

First, uninstall postgreSQL. (you can open Finder - Applications - Drag the folder of PostgreSQL X into Trash - enter password)

Second, follow [the steps of JacksonWong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72875932/16981588) to delete the postgres users by:

- `dscl . list /Users` to find out all postgres or _postgres users, and remove them with:
- `sudo dscl . -delete /Users/_postgres`
- `sudo dscl . -delete /Users/postgres`

Third, click the apple icon() on the upper left side of the screen - System Preferences - Users & Groups -  Click the lock to make changes - the '+' under ' Login Options' - set Full Name, Account Name both to be: `postgres`, no need to enter any password - Create User

Then, remember to RESTART the computer.

Finally, rerun the PostgreSQL installer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zoey Zhou for explaining how to delete the user.  You can't delete the user from the System Settings window otherwise.

Manually delete the application here:
open /Library/PostgreSQL/15/uninstall-postgresql.app
(or whatever folder in Library you have installed the software).

You will then get a message that the data directory folder and service user account have not been removed.  Manually search for and delete any folders (look in Library and Apps).  Empty the trash.  Delete the users.

Create the new user in System Settings -- you will be required to give it a password.

Reboot.  Rerun the installer. It should work fine now.  Go back and delete the postgres user from the System Settings window (including the associated folder).

I suspect (but have no data) that this may be related to doing a transfer from an older computer to the new M1, as I did not have these issues with my laptop.

Answer (score -2):

I've run with the same problem and here is my solution:

1. Remove/Uninstall postgreSQL.
2. Download the latest postgreSQL
3. Create a usernamed "postgres" in System preferences under Users & Groups.
4. Run the installer.
5. Remove the user you created since you won't be using this to login.