# Downloading PostgreSQL on Mac

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, download

I've been having problems downloading PostgreSQL on my Mac. I attempted to download multiple versions but keep on getting the same error message shown in the attached picture."Problem running post install - step. Installation may not complete correctly.the database cluster installation failed."

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sy8C.png)

Answer (score 0):

Answer available on another post

[PostgresSQL Installation fails: "database cluster initialisation failed" MAC os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189729/postgressql-installation-fails-database-cluster-initialisation-failed-mac-os)

or

Try via Docker, its easy and works all the time. :)