# PostgreSQL: database cluster initialisation failed for Mac OS

Tags: postgresql, macos

I am currently running Catalina 10.15 and I keep experiencing issues when trying to download postgresql. Namely:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
> correctly The database cluster initialisation failed.

I have tried this [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189729/postgressql-installation-fails-database-cluster-initialisation-failed-mac-os) to no avail. Am I supposed to run that command from the root dir, I ran it from user directory. It seemed to work in any case as a new user PostgreSQL was created.

Let me know if I can provide more information, I have been struggling for hours.

edit: Whenever I save it to /Library/PostgreSQL/13 it doesn't save it to library but Applications instead.