# PostgresSQL 9.5 Installation fails: “database cluster initialisation failed” MAC os (big sur 11.4)

Tags: postgresql, macos, postgresql-9.5

I am installing PostgreSQL (V 9.5) on macOS Before it finishes installing I am getting the following error macOS (big sur 11.4)

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly The database cluster initialisation failed.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall PostgresSQL and then clean /Library/PostgreSQL/ directory.
Open teminal and run:

```sh
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres UserShell /bin/sh

sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres NFSHomeDirectory /Library/PostgreSQL
```

Install PostgresSQL

please refer [PostgresSQL Installation fails: "database cluster initialisation failed" MAC os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189729/postgressql-installation-fails-database-cluster-initialisation-failed-mac-os)

Comment: i applied this method but after running these commands in my mac os 11.4 and installing again postgres 9.5 it's not installing

Comment: Can you try creating user after installation step ?

1. Uninstall PostgresSQL and then clean /Library/PostgreSQL/ Directory.
2. Open teminal and run :
3. sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres UserShell /bin/sh
4. sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres NFSHomeDirectory /Library/PostgreSQL
5. Install PostgresSQL

Comment: Thank you Nikhil B Now i follow the same and do not restart system. Finally install postgresql 9.5