# How to delete user via terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I'm having some issues installing Postgres and have been trying a few different approaches. I eventually followed [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189729/postgressql-installation-fails-database-cluster-initialisation-failed-mac-os) which meant I had to run the following command in terminal...

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres UserShell /bin/sh
sudo dscl . -create /Users/postgres NFSHomeDirectory /Library/PostgreSQL
```

However, this did not resolve issue I'm having with installing Postgres.

I then attempted to added postgres users via system preference but ran into the error of "Name already used by another user". However I cannot see this users!

[image].

How can I effectively delete the postgres user created in the above command? The goal is to add the users via system preferences instead.

I can see the hidden user by using this command:

```
dscl . -list /Users
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -delete "/Users/postgres"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. List all User Accounts

> ```
> $ /usr/bin/dscl . -list /Users
> ```

2. Follow the command to Delete a User Account

> ```
> $ /usr/bin/dscl . -delete/ Users/<USER_ACCOUNT>
> ```

3. Show a User Account Information

> ```
> $ /usr/bin/dscl . -read /Users/<USER_ACCOUNT>
> ```